# flexjs install produces 4K mxmlc.jar?

Tags: flexjs

I tried to install FlexJS using the *Download the binary package and use Ant* [described here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLEX/Getting+Started+With+FlexJS#GettingStartedWithFlexJS-Binary).

After running `ant -f install.xml` the mxmlc.jar that gets created is only 4KB without any class files in it.

Appreciate any hints on this.

Answer (score 0):

I re-tried the "npm install flexjs" and it installed v0.7.1 fine. After installing to c:\try_flexjs I set 
FALCON_HOME=c:\try_flexjs\node_modules\flexjs
and FLEX_HOME=c:\try_flexjs\node_modules\flexjs

I can then run the HelloWorld [example](https://nextgenactionscript.com/tutorials/hello-world-transpile-actionscript-apache-flexjs/) as described.